# UIView layoutMargins with a custom shape

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I want to create an UIView with a circular shape but also I want its layoutMargins follow that shape.

For example if I add a subview at the top it will have less left and right margin that it would have had if I added it at the center.

Comment: What you can do is to create a custom view which does that behavior. You can probably override `addSubview` to layout subview as you want. I don't think there's any out of box way. UITextView has something similar though.

Comment: Thanks I will try